# How to display marker on given Latitude and longitude values using google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an app using google map.In this i want to show google map of provided values of latitude and longitude.In app i fetch the latitude and longitude values from database and at this values of latitude and longitude i want to show marker on google map.

Following is the code which i used, In below code i show fetched values of latitude and longitude and also marker show on this fetch values of latitude and longitude on google map but the problem is when i run the app first time map show accurately at fetched values of latitude and longitude but when i open the app second time it shows blue on map.I want to show map at fetched values of latitude and longitude.How do i do this?

```
//java code
public class Location_Track6 extends FragmentActivity {

    JSONArray result = null;

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String CON = "CON";
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    SupportMapFragment fm;

    private String url ="";

    private static final String TAG_USER = "result";

    //   private static final String TAG_SNAME = "pseats";
    private static final String TAG_LONG = "longitude";
    private static final String TAG_LAT = "latitude";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "paddress";

    private List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
    Polyline line; //added

    TextView tv_mobno, tv_latitude, tv_longitude, tv_time;
    String getLatitude;
    String getLongitude;
    Button slocation;

    TextView etLng, etLat;
    Button btnShow;

    double lati=0;
    double lngi=0;

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.location_track6);

        tv_mobno=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_mob);
        tv_latitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_latitude);
        tv_longitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_longitude);
        tv_time=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_time);

        etLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_lat);
        etLng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_lng);

        fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        //    slocation=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_slocation);

        url = "http://example.in/gmap_track.php";


// Getting reference to button btn_show
        btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show);

        new JSONParse().execute();

// Setting click event listener for the button
        btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                getUserLocation();


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Location_Track6.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {

                // Getting JSON Array
                result = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
                JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);


                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String lat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
                String lng = c.getString(TAG_LONG);


                //Set JSON Data in TextView

                etLat.setText(lat);
                etLng.setText(lng);


                lati = Double.parseDouble(etLat.getText().toString());
                lngi = Double.parseDouble(etLng.getText().toString());

                //    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati, lng)).title("point");
                //    googleMap.addMarker(marker);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    private  void getUserLocation(){

        LatLng position = new LatLng(lati, lngi);

        // Instantiating MarkerOptions class
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting position for the MarkerOptions
        options.position(position);

        // Setting title for the MarkerOptions
        options.title("Position");

        // Setting snippet for the MarkerOptions
        options.snippet("Latitude:"+lati+",Longitude:"+lngi);

        // Getting Reference to SupportMapFragment of activity_map.xml


        // Getting reference to google map
        googleMap = fm.getMap();

        // Adding Marker on the Google Map
        googleMap.addMarker(options);

        // Creating CameraUpdate object for position
        CameraUpdate updatePosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position);

        // Creating CameraUpdate object for zoom
        CameraUpdate updateZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(13);

        // Updating the camera position to the user input latitude and longitude
        googleMap.moveCamera(updatePosition);

        // Applying zoom to the marker position
        googleMap.animateCamera(updateZoom);
    }

    private void addMarker() {
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

        // following four lines requires 'Google Maps Android API Utility Library'
        // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/
        // I have used this to display the time as title for location markers
        // you can safely comment the following four lines but for this info
    /*    IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(this);
        iconFactory.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_PURPLE);
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon(String.valueOf(R.drawable.one))));
        options.anchor(iconFactory.getAnchorU(), iconFactory.getAnchorV());
    */
        LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(lati,lngi);
        options.position(currentLatLng);
        Marker mapMarker = googleMap.addMarker(options);
        //    long atTime = mCurrentLocation.getTime();
        //    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date(atTime));
        //    mapMarker.setTitle(mLastUpdateTime);
        mapMarker.setTitle("point");
       // Log.d(TAG, "Marker added.............................");
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng,
                13));
       // Log.d(TAG, "Zoom done.............................");
    }
}
```

Comment: check your log for errors when map is getting blank second time and post it here so we can help better.

Comment: logcat shows only maps api links their is no error

Answer (score 1):

For displaying  marker by static or give Latitude and Longitude

```
lat = 22.368025;
lon =91.849106;
loc = new LatLng(lat, lon);
marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("Hello Chittagong").snippet("A nice city"));
```

For changing marker color

```
marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));`
```

Zoom in the position

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 11.0f));
```